# Problem with sudo and gksudo - cannot open display and no focus on password

Tags: sudo, gparted

I have following problems:

1. cannot open display

   ```
   $ sudo gparted

   Created symlink /run/systemd/system/-.mount → /dev/null.
   Created symlink /run/systemd/system/home.mount → /dev/null.
   Created symlink /run/systemd/system/media-user-F0XXXXXXE.mount → /dev/null.
   Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-1000.mount → /dev/null.
   Created symlink /run/systemd/system/run-user-123.mount → /dev/null.
   Created symlink /run/systemd/system/tmp.mount → /dev/null.
   No protocol specified

   (gpartedbin:9503): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
   ```
2. When running

   ```
   gksu anyappname
   ```

   the password prompt not receiving focus, it is still on terminal, so I can't type my password. Even if I paste it, terminal output is same as step 1.

What should I do?

Comment: what version of ubuntu and why are you making all those links ?

Comment: @Panther I don't how they appear and how they was created. I have only set to automatically one of my ntfs partitions mounting at startup...